# How to have a common label for all x and y axes in case of subplots?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, axis-labels, axes, subplot

I have used the following loop to get subplots:

```
for j=1:19;
    Aj=B(j,:);
    subplot(5,4,j);
    plot(Aj,h)
end
```

For all these subplots, I need to have only one x-label and one y-label. How to do this? Also how to insert legend to all the subplots?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**`suplabel`**](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7772-suplabel) from the *FileExchange* to have combined *x* and *y* label for all subplots.

**Example:**

```
subplot(1,2,1);
plot(randperm(40)); hold on; plot(randperm(40));  %Plotting some random data
legend('show')   %To show the legend

subplot(1,2,2);
plot(randperm(40)); hold on; plot(randperm(40));  %Plotting some random data
legend('show')   %To show the legend

%Using suplabel from the FileExchange to give a single x and y label for all subplots
suplabel('Combined X label','x');
suplabel('Combined Y label','y');
```

**Output:**

[image: outputsuplabel]

---

<sup>Sometimes you have to maximize the figure window to see the *xlabel* when using [**`suplabel`**](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7772-suplabel).</sup>